# Share login between .NET Core 2 web app and VueJS spa

Tags: api, authentication, single-page-application, asp.net-core-2.0

Perhaps this is a stupid question, but I honestly don't know where to start.

I currently have a .NET Core 2 MVC project using Entity Framework. In this MVC app a user can:

- sign up
- confirm his email
- login
- change password and add basic profile information
- reset his password using "forgot password"

Now I want to build a VueJS SPA in which the user can log in as well using .net core 2 webapi. All the hooks for this api are already build and are working as expected.

The MVC, API and SPA parts would all live on a separate subdomains:

- www.site.com for MVC
- app.site.com for SPA
- api.site.com for API

### My question: Is there a way to let the user:

1. Login using the MVC website *or* spa/webapi
2. Share the login on both systems (when going back to the marketing website, a "Go to app" button appears and the SPA recognizes the authenticated user

The same behavior can be found on the website www.clubhouse.io. This seems to be exactly how I'd like my website to work :)

Comment: How do you authenticate users in MVC application? If you use cookieless authentication, you can easily share the token across origins. I'm using JWT token sent in request header and it should work in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The de-facto technology for what you're after is [OAuth 2.0](https://oauth.net/2/).

You'll need a component to act as an identity provider, which (depending on your requirements) may federate with social identity providers too.

As with most things security, rolling your own authorisation server is a really, *really* bad idea. Plus, it's already a (mostly) solved problem.

Realistically you've got a few choices:

1. Use a third party identity service (Okta, auth0, etc)
2. Use a standalone, off-the-shelf authorisation server product
3. Integrate an off-the-shelf authorisation server library

Given you already have a server-side rendered MVC application, #3 is probably the best approach.

Right now it looks like the best tool out there for .NET is [IdentityServer.io](http://identityserver.io/). I'd head over that way and get cracking for implementation.

A helpful hint along the way: given your SPA application can't keep a secret (its source code is fully available to clients), the only appropriate authorization grant type is "Implicit".